# Javascript protoytpe conflict with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, grails

Running Grails application that allows for users to display html table output via PDF or Excel.
Conflict issue when javascript protoype library is called in pair with jquery;

For PDF functionality to execute, Prototype library required:

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" />
```

For Excel to be created, am using jquery's table2excel:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<g:javascript src="jquery/jquery.table2excel.js"/>
```

Both can not run in pair!
Trying to identify a solution that enables both protoype and jquery to run in collateral.

Here are the function calls:

```
function submitPdf() {
var formValues =
    'compCode='+$('cmpCode').value+
    ...
    ...
    ...
    '&pdf=true'+
    '&userEmail='+'${user.email}'
formValues = escape(formValues);
var url = '/${meta(name:'app.name')}/pdf/show?url=/salesAnalysis/analyze?'+formValues+'&pdf=true';
window.location=url;
```

}

```
function displayAsCsv() {
$('.salesAnalysis').table2excel({
   exclude: ".noExl",
   name: "Sales Analysis",
   filename: "SalesAnalysis"
});
```

}

Comment: The 1.4.2 version of jQuery is seven years old.

Comment: Why can they not be used together? Because prototype also uses $ as its variable name?

Comment: What error shows?